# #Storm: how to setup various metrics for the same data source

Tags: apache-storm

I'm trying to setup Storm to aggregate a stream, but with various (DRPC available) metrics on the same stream.

E.g. the stream is consisted of messages that have a sender, a recipient, the channel through which the message arrived and a gateway through which it was delivered. I'm having trouble deciding how to organize one or more topologies that could give me e.g. total count of messages by gateway and/or by channel. And besides the total, counts per minute would be nice too.

The basic idea is to have a spout that will accept messaging events, and from there aggregate the data as needed. Currently I'm playing around with Trident and DRPC and I've came up with two possible topologies that solve the problem at this stage. Can't decide which approach is better, if any?!

The entire source is available at this **[gist](https://gist.github.com/elvanja/6577832)**.
It has three classes:

- *[RandomMessageSpout](https://gist.github.com/elvanja/6577832#file-randommessagespout-java)*

  - used to emit the messaging data
  - simulates the real data source
- *[SeparateTopology](https://gist.github.com/elvanja/6577832#file-separatetopology-java)*

  - creates a separate DRPC stream for each metric needed
  - also a separate query state is created for each metric
  - they all use the same spout instance
- *[CombinedTopology](https://gist.github.com/elvanja/6577832#file-combinedtopology-java)*

  - creates a single DRPC stream with all the metrics needed
  - creates a separate query state for each metric
  - each query state extracts the desired metric and groups results for it

Now, for the problems and questions:

- *[SeparateTopology](https://gist.github.com/elvanja/6577832#file-separatetopology-java)*

  - is it necessary to use the same spout instance or can I just say new RandomMessageSpout() each time?
  - I like the idea that I don't need to persist grouped data by all the metrics, but just the groupings we need to extract later
  - is the spout emitted data actually processed by all the state/query combinations, e.g. not the first one that comes?
  - would this also later enable dynamic addition of new state/query combinations at runtime?
- *[CombinedTopology](https://gist.github.com/elvanja/6577832#file-combinedtopology-java)*

  - I don't really like the idea that I need to persist data grouped by all the metrics since I don't need all the combinations
  - it came as a surprise that the all the metrics always return the same data

    - e.g. channel and gateway inquiries return status metrics data
    - I found that this was always the data grouped by the first field in [state definition](https://gist.github.com/elvanja/6577832#file-combinedtopology-java-L40)
    - [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/storm-user/Hgmd9HAXCOY/_atGWPOWWaYJ) explains the reasoning behind this behaviour
    - but I'm wondering if this is a good way of doing thins in the first place (and will find a way around this issue if need be)
- *SnapshotGet vs TupleCollectionGet in stateQuery*

  - with SnapshotGet things tended to work, but not always, only TupleCollectionGet solved the issue
  - any pointers as to what is correct way of doing that?

I guess this is a longish question / topic, but any help is really appreciated!
Also, if I missed the architecture entirely, suggestions on how to accomplish this would be most welcome.
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually split a stream in `SeparateTopology` by invoking `newStream()` using the same spout instance, since that would create new instances of the same `RandomMessageSpout` spout, which would result in duplicate values being emitted to your topology by multiple, separate spout instances. (Spout parallelization is only possible in Storm with partitioned spouts, where each spout instance processes a partition of the whole dataset -- a Kafka partition, for example).

The correct approach here is to modify the `CombinedTopology` to split the stream into multiple streams as needed for each metric you need (see below), and then do a `groupBy()` by that metric's field and `persistentAggregate()` on each newly branched stream.

From the Trident FAQ,

> "each" returns a Stream object, which you can store in a variable. You can then run multiple eaches on the same Stream to split it, e.g.:
>
> ```
> Stream s = topology.each(...).groupBy(...).aggregate(...)
> Stream branch1 = s.each(...)
> Stream branch2 = s.each(...)
> ```

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/__ZfsFChkn8) on Storm's mailing list, and [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/storm-user/memorymapstate/storm-user/7irjxIe-jao/-6VnuGYpQB4J) for more information.